# HTTP Status Code for Location-Based Redirect

Tags: http, redirect, http-status-codes, http-redirect

I have a webpage that when landed on, will detect a user's physical location and then redirect them to the page most appropriate for the user.

What HTTP Status Code should be used for this redirect?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I believe that HTTP 303 is probably the most appropriate status code for a situation like this, though it may not be compatible with pre-HTTP 1.1 clients.

The [HTTP 303](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.4) Status Code states (Note: I have bolded the parts that I feel are most important):
**The response to the request can be found under a different URI and SHOULD be retrieved using a GET method on that resource.** This method exists primarily to allow the output of a POST-activated script to redirect the user agent to a selected resource. **The new URI is not a substitute reference for the originally requested resource. The 303 response MUST NOT be cached, but the response to the second (redirected) request might be cacheable.**

Comment: Actually, you should have bolded the exact opposite part of the text: “This method exists primarily to allow the output of a POST-activated script to redirect the user agent to a selected resource.”

Answer (score 1):

If there is a URI for the requester to utilize that would allow them to end up the same place without a redirect, then a 303 makes sense ([as sjstrutt answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11163721/662565)) as they should use the new location's URI.  If not, a 302 makes sense to me because they *should* continue to use the Request-URI for future requests as you will then be redirecting them to a location lacking a URI they could otherwise request.

Heres what [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.3) says about 302 status codes:

> 10.3.3 302 Found
>
> The requested resource resides temporarily under a different URI.
>   **Since the redirection might be altered on occasion, the client SHOULD
>   continue to use the Request-URI for future requests.** This response is
>   only cacheable if indicated by a Cache-Control or Expires header
>   field.
>
> The temporary URI SHOULD be given by the Location field in the
>   response. Unless the request method was HEAD, the entity of the
>   response SHOULD contain a short hypertext note with a hyperlink to the
>   new URI(s).
>
> If the 302 status code is received in response to a request other than
>   GET or HEAD, the user agent MUST NOT automatically redirect the
>   request unless it can be confirmed by the user, since this might
>   change the conditions under which the request was issued.
>
> ...

Emphasis mine.

As an aside: CodeIgniter's [`redirect()`](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html) function defaults to 302, but mentions a 301 might be used for search engine redirects.  Obviously that was their decision, but I figured I would throw that into the mix as it is a widely used web framework and I assume they have put some thought into it.

Answer (score 1):

The appropriate response status code for a successful content negotiation is either [301](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.3.2), [302](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.3.3), or [307](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.3.8), depending on whether the redirect is permanent or only temporary.

But in any case, server-driven negotiation should always state which information the decision was based on. In HTTP, it’s the *Vary* response header field that specifies a list of request header fields that were used in this process.

Unfortunately, the client’s IP address (I guess you’re translating those into geolocation information) is not an option here. So a permanent redirect is not an option either, unless you indicate the response not to be cached, otherwise it could be cached by clients or intermediary proxies. So I would either use 302 or 307.